# How to remove any widget from a list and set its state in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform, flutter-container

Here i am creating an app which contain a section through which a user can create a poll. So when i am pressing a add button options container get added but when i am trying to remove the option container by pressing the minus button it's not working. Can someone help me to fix this. This is my college project.

[image: application preview]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:note_app_demo/scaffold.dart';

List<Container> options = [
  Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
    child: TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        hintText: 'Option 1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
];

class POLL extends StatefulWidget {
  const POLL({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _POLLState createState() => _POLLState();
}

class _POLLState extends State<POLL> {
  int option_var = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SCAFFOLD(
      BODY: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  hintText: 'Write your question here',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: options,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        options.removeAt(option_var);
                      });
                      option_var--;
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.remove_circle,
                      size: 60,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      option_var++;
                      if (option_var < 9) {
                        setState(() {
                          options.add(
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                              child: TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                  hintText: 'Option $option_var',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.add_circle,
                      size: 60,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.check_circle,
                  size: 60,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you trigger the widget rebuild upon calling **setState** the **option_var** gets reset to 1. At the top of the build method, when setting the value of the **option_var**, use instead:

```dart
int option_var = options.length;
```

which will reflect the accurate number of items in the collection, thus keeping your count in sync.

Then, in your removal code, just do:

```dart
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
     option_var--;
     options.removeAt(option_var);
  });         
},
```

Where you keep the **option_var** updated, and you always remove from the end of the array.

It should look like this after the updates:

[image]

Good luck in your project!

Comment: Thanks  brother for solving my issue it means a lot.

Comment: No problem. Go ahead and mark the answer as correct!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I checked the code, the addition works. When deleting an error occurs that the number is 1 more than necessary.

Changed instead of option_var made option_var-1
Therefore o

```
   onTap: () {
                       setState(() {
                         options.removeAt(option_var-1);
                       });
                       option_var--;
                     },
```

made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there are many reasons why this might be happening, or rather there are many unconventional things going on with your code, so I am not sure if changing just one of them will fix the bug.

The first obvious thing you have to change is this:

```
onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    options.removeAt(option_var);
  });
  option_var--;
},
```

Imagine you have a single item on your list, `options_var` should be equal to 1. So you are saying:

> remove the item in position number 1.

But remember, lists count from 0, so the item in position number one would be the second item on your list. You should use position 0.

A simple way to fix this is to move the `--` operator to before your set state.

```
onTap: () {
  option_var--;
  setState(() {
    options.removeAt(option_var);
  });
},
```

I will also let you know that lists, like options, have a `length` variable that gets updated automatically and works exactly the same as your `option_var` does, so you could use it instead:

```
onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    options.removeAt(options.length-1);
  });
},
```

The other two things that you could change are as follows:

1. I like to use `setState` with explicit assignments:

```
onTap: () {
  var _options = options.removeAt(options.length-1);
  setState(() {
    options = _options;
  });
},
```

2. I would make options be a `_POLLState` variable, like `option_var`

Comment: Thanks a lot brother i got it. I liked your another approach too.